# Dojo dijit.Dialog Animation

Tags: animation, dojo, dialog

How can one make `dijit.Dialog` to fade in a given time period? Is there any way define it?

I have created above dialog in a method. But I need to call the method frequently. So it will create multiple dialogs. So how to block(not to appear) other dialogs until visible dialog get faded?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    // Require the Dialog class
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    // Create counter
    var counter = 1;
    // Create a new Dialog
    function createDialog(first) {
        // Create a new dialog
        var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({
            // Dialog title
            title: "New Dialog " + counter,
            // Create Dialog content
            content: (!first ? "I am a dialog on top of other dialogs" : "I am the bottom dialog") + "<br /><br /><button onclick='createDialog();'>Create another dialog.</button>"
        });
        dialog.show();
        counter++;
    } </script> <button onclick="createDialog(true);">Create New Dialog</button>
```